# Call a function inside Flutter Widget

Tags: flutter, function, dart, oop, widget

I am pretty new to OOP and Flutter. I created the following widget and want to call the widget function when creating it inside another stateless Widget.

My plan is to create the widget as a child and then use the defined variable *widgetState* to check if it is true and if it is, it should call the void *printSample()* function. The conditional check shout be triggered by onTap of the widget (InkWell).

Widget with the Function:

```
class WhiteCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final widgetState = true;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Color switchColor = Colors.red;

  void printSample() {
    print("Sample text");
  }
  
  const WhiteCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 320,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ScreenController.isLargeScreen(context)
              ? Text("large")
              : ScreenController.isMediumScreen(context)
                  ? Text("medium")
                  : Text("small"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Widget that calls the WhiteCard()

```
class LargeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LargeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: WhiteCard(
            onTap: () {
              CALL THE FUNCTION FROM WIDGET);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define a function to leave the definition of object cleaner:

```
class LargeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LargeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  onTapFunction() {
    // write he whatever you need to do when taping widget
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: WhiteCard(
            onTap: onTapFunction,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So if you need to call the onTapFunction from elsewhere, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood your question correctly then your onTap should be something like this:

```
onTap: () {
  if (widgetState) {
     printSample();
  }
```

Good luck, Feel free to respond if you have queries